# PCL XL Error

Tags: printing, hp

When printing from Adobe Photoshop Album Starter Edition to a network printer (HP Color LaserJet 3600) this error message is printed out rather than the photographs. Any ideas?

```
PCL XL error
    Subsystem: KERNEL
    Error:     IllegalTag
    Operator:  0xa2
    Position:  3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using PCL 6 XL (Enhanced) printer drivers, PCL XL error pages usually indicate a communication problem. The error can also be caused by an incompatibility between the Enhanced XL language and the software application that is associated with the file being printed, Adobe Photoshop Album in your case.

The procedure in this [HP support document](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&objectID=c00064499) for a different Laserjet model should help determining the source of the problem.

In most cases the PCL5e drivers are recommended over PCL6 drivers. They work just as well and won't throw such errors. PCL 6 XL is less forgiving of slight glitches in the printer driver or software. PCL5e has been around longer and is considered more stable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Upgraded to the latest version of the drivers and the problem seems to be resolved... for now anyways. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the PCL6 driver, try the PCL5 driver or PS driver.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a problem with the driver -- [see these](http://www.planet-winner.com/web2/KB/Front_Office/PCL_XL_Error_when_printing_to_HP_Laserjet_printers.htm) [links.](http://forums11.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/bizsupport/questionanswer.do?admit=109447626+1242418126095+28353475&threadId=1062280)

If you have an option to use a postscript driver rather than PCL you might get better results, seems true for a lot of Adobe products.

Comment: I second the PS vs. PCL comment.  I've found that postscript tends to have less issues (which has always surprised me since PCL is HP's thing).